# variable-length-arguments in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have learned that this code will print 10, 30, 60 in Terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int num, ...);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a=10, b=20, c=30;

    add(1, a);
    add(2, a, b);
    add(3, a, b, c);

    return 0;
}

void add(int num, ...)
{
    int* p = NULL;
    p = &num + 1;

    if (num == 1)
        printf("%d \n", p[0]);
    else if (num == 2)
        printf("%d \n", p[0] + p[1]);
    else
        printf("%d \n", p[0] + p[1] + p[2]);
}
```

But, it only print odd numbers... :(
I just want to print 10, 30, 60 within .
Where do you think I should fix?

Comment: If you really want to use variadic functions, you should use [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg) and do it properly. This code you have is terrible. Secondly, you should probably say _specifically_ what you want it to do, and what it actually does, and what you've tried to fix it. But fix the `va_arg` thing first!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071186/function-with-unknown-number-of-parameters-in-c

Comment: [as sample code(sum)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266152/971127)

Comment: That's so very undefined behaviour …

Comment: "I have learned that this code will print 10, 30, 60 in Terminal." - Where did you learn this? You teacher should learn C basics before teaching if he presents such code. That was not valid in the last 28 years **at least**.

Comment: @HeavyLight Was it your teacher that told you this, or are you reading a web site, or book?

Comment: @Neil from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry2g1ck7dN4&index=92&list=PL7mmuO705dG3Z4iSqwzztuPHF3YE8mlbw) at 01:14.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get variadic arguments just by taking the address of the last given parameter and adding to it.  How function arguments are laid out on the stack (if a stack is used) is compiler and system dependent.  That's why you're getting strange numbers.

The way to do this portably is to use a `va_list` as follows:

```
void add(int num, ...)
{
    // the va_list used to retrieve the extra arguments
    va_list args;                  
    int i, sum = 0;

    // use va_start to start processing arguments, passing in the last explicit argument
    va_start(args, num);           
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        // extract the next argument with the given type
        sum += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    // cleanup
    va_end(args);

    printf("%d \n", sum);
}
```

For more details, see the [stdarg man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look around.